# How to force autoconf to not define a macro?

Tags: c, autoconf

I regularly run into this problem while building C projects that use autoconf so I'm looking for a repeatable way to do this. I often have a library where I'd like to `undef` a macro that is generated by autoheader in a `config.h` file. For example - right now I want to make sure that `#define CLOCK_GETTIME 1` is generated as `#undef CLOCK_GETTIME`.

Assume in this example the `clock_gettime` is checked like so.

```
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([clock_gettime])
```

In the past I manually edit the file to remove defines. But I can't believe there isn't something I cant just pass to `./configure` to override the default behavior of `AC_CHECK_FUNCS`.

How do I change what autoconf decides to define in my `config.h`?

Comment: What is the requirement to remove the defines?

Comment: Its a standard `config.h` autoheader style file. The requirement is simply to have autoconf produce an `#undef MACRO` where a `#define MACRO 1` would normally appear.

The *why* this is necessary is that sometimes there are open-source libraries I'd like to use but want, or need, to customize. The code supports it - but I can't make the `autoconf` do what I'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./configure 'ac_cv_func_clock_gettime=no'` should work.  For example:

```sh
mkdir foo
cd foo
printf '%s\n' \
    'AC_INIT([foo], [0.1])' \
    'AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])' \
    'AC_CHECK_FUNCS([clock_gettime])' \
    'AC_OUTPUT' \
    > configure.ac
autoheader
autoconf
./configure >/dev/null 2>&1 \
    && grep CLOCK_GETTIME config.h
./configure 'ac_cv_func_clock_gettime=no' >/dev/null 2>&1 \
    && grep CLOCK_GETTIME config.h
```

Output on my system:

```c
#define HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME 1
/* #undef HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME */
```

All cache variables created by `AC_CHECK_FUNC`, `AC_CHECK_FUNCS`, and `AC_CHECK_FUNCS_ONCE` have a general form described in [the official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/Generic-Functions.html#index-AC_005fCHECK_005fFUNC-1):

> This macro caches its result in the `ac_cv_func_function` variable.

Here are some more examples:

```
ac_cv_func_strcasecmp        # AC_CHECK_FUNC([strcasecmp])
ac_cv_func_mempcpy           # AC_CHECK_FUNC([mempcpy])
ac_cv_func_pthread_create    # AC_CHECK_FUNC([pthread_create])
```